# Яндекс Облако Serverless: как загрузить файл?

Tags: яндекс-облако

Хочу загрузить файл в облако от пользователя по хттп апи и хранить его в объектном хранилище 3 дня, и передать на обработку в serverless функцию.

Где есть пример про загрузку файлов в Объектное хранилищи от пользователей без выделения спец сервера (в SaaS режиме)?